# What do you think about this conjecture?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, gamma-function, conjectures

Beforehand, please know that I'm a little bit of an amateur mathemitician, so this could be very wrong. But, I have tested it over and over and over again and it seems to be plausible, but there's still other things that I haven't tried that might possibly prove it wrong. That's why it's a 'conjecture' and not a 'theorem' or definitely not a 'law'.

This conjencture involves functions. Any function. Let's say we have the function $f(x)$. Obviously, this doesn't mean I just multiply f by x, it is a function of x. But, what if there was a way to separate the two? Well, I came up with this simple equation as the base of this entire conjecture:

$$f(x)=f*Ƨx$$ 
where $f$ is the function modifier and $Ƨx$ is the terminal, meaning what the function modifier is in terms of. The first problem with this is $Ƨx$. This is not a number or anything like that. It is its own concept, but it can be utilized in an equation. The second problem with this is $f$. How do he know that f is used in a function, and that it's not variable? Well, we don't know, unless it is blatantly defined as a *function modifier*. Usually, it is assumed that it's a function modifier, since it is in front of $Ƨx$ and it's 'f', probably the most commonly used function modifier. Simply put, **$f(x)$ is the same as a function modifier $f$ multiplied by a value that has $Ƨ$ in front of it.** There is no operation that can add $Ƨ$ in front of a value, $Ƨ$ can only be taken from an actually function.

Since:
$$f(x) = f*Ƨx$$
Therefore: 
$$f = f*Ƨx/Ƨx$$
and Also:
$$Ƨx = f*Ƨx/f$$

With this conjecture, I can find the solution to some problems:

1. find $g(x)$ in terms of $a$ and $b$, assuming $f$ and $g$ are both function modifiers
   $$f(a)+f(b)=g(a+b)$$
   Solve: 
   $$f(a)+f(b)=g*Ƨ(a+b)$$
   $$(f(a)+f(b))/Ƨ(a+b)=g$$
   $$(f(a)+f(b))/Ƨ(a+b)*Ƨx = g*Ƨx$$
   $$(f(a)+f(b))Ƨx/Ƨ(a+b)=g(x)$$
   Assuming $f/f=1$ (which it should)
   $$f/f *(f(a)+f(b))Ƨx/Ƨ(a+b)=g(x)$$
   $$((f(a)+f(b))f*Ƨx)/f*Ƨ(a+b)=g(x)$$
   $$((f(a)+f(b))f(x))/f(a+b)=g(x)$$
   So my solution is:
   $$((f(a)+f(b))f(x))/f(a+b)=g(x)$$

Now after some tests, this proves to be right. I'll try to prove it here by saying $f(x)=2x-1$. This next problem will be similar to the last problem, excpet that $f(x)$ will now be defined.

2. find $g(x)$, assuming $f$ and $g$ are both function modifiers. $f(x)=2x-1$
   $$f(a)+f(b)=g(a+b)$$
   Solve: 
   $$((f(a)+f(b))f(x))/f(a+b)=g(x)$$
   $$((2a-1)+(2b-1))(2x-1)/(2(a+b)-1)=g(x)$$
   $$(2a-1+2b-1)(2x-1)/(2a+2b-1)=g(x)$$
   $$(2a+2b-2)(2x-1)/(2a+2b-1)=g(x)$$
   $$(4ax-2a+4bx-2b-2x+2)/(2a+2b-1)=g(x)$$
   Now let's see if $g(x)$ really is equal to that...
   $$f(a)+f(b) = 2a-1+2b-1 = 2a+2b-2$$
   Let's plug in $a+b$ into $g(x)$ to see if it's equal to $f(a)+f(b)$
   $$((2a-1)+(2b-1))(2(a+b)-1)/(2(a+b)-1)=g(a+b)$$
   The $2(a+b)-1$ in the nominator cancels out with the $2(a+b)-1$ in the denominator:
   $$(2a-1)+(2b-1)=g(a+b)$$
   $$2a+2b-1=g(a+b)$$
   And, it works! If you're thinking this, I also thought that it was a little suspicious that the nominator and the denominator cancel out, but considering I used $Ƨx$ as the basis, that suspicion decreased.

I've also used this conjecture to find another way to define the Gamma Function($\Gamma(x)$) using this definition:
$$\Gamma(1-x)\Gamma(x)=\pi/sin(\pi*x)$$
$$\Gamma*Ƨ(1-x)\Gamma*Ƨ(x)=\pi/sin(\pi*x)$$
$$\Gamma^2*Ƨ(1-x)(Ƨx)= \pi/sin(\pi*x)$$
$$\Gamma^2*Ƨx=\pi/sin(\pi*x)Ƨ(x-1)$$
$$\Gamma^2*Ƨx*Ƨx=\pi/sin(\pi*x)Ƨ(x-1) *Ƨx$$
$$(\Gamma*Ƨx)^2=\pi/sin(\pi*x)Ƨ(x-1) *Ƨx$$
$$(\Gamma(x))^2=\pi/sin(\pi*x)Ƨ(x-1) *Ƨx$$
$$\Gamma(x)=sqrt((\pi*Ƨx)/(sin(\pi*x)Ƨ(x-1)))$$
However, this solution can not be used to directly utilize the function, since we don't know what $Ƨx$ and $Ƨ(x-1)$ are, so it stays like that. Since it doesn't involve any other function, I can't multiply the numerator and denominator by a function operator.

I've also used this conjecture to attempt to a find a way to define antiderivation. Now I COULD be very wrong on this because I don't really take into account the limit, which I have a feeling I should be, and I'm only assuming that $h$ is still approaching $0$ after all of this.

$$f'(x)= lim(h>0) (f(x+h)-f(x))/h$$
$$f'(x)= lim(h>0) (f*Ƨ(x+h)-f*Ƨ(x))/h$$
$$f'(x)= lim(h>0) (f*(Ƨ(x+h)-Ƨ(x)))/h$$
$$f'(x)*h= lim(h>0) f*(Ƨ(x+h)-Ƨ(x))$$
$$(f'(x)*h)/(Ƨ(x+h)-Ƨx) = lim(h>0) f$$
$$(f'(x)*h)/(Ƨ(x+h)-Ƨx)*Ƨx = lim(h>0) f*Ƨx$$
$$(hf'(x)*Ƨx)/(Ƨ(x+h)-Ƨx) = lim(h>0) f(x)$$
$$ f(x) = lim(h>0)(hf'(x)*Ƨx)/(Ƨ(x+h)-Ƨx)$$

**This is proven to be wrong, since h is not defined outside of the limit, but still, it shows the use of my conjecture.**

And so, this has been my conjecture. I don't know if it's solid, and I hope it doesn't get disproved (most likely will), but even if I'm redefining something that I didn't know existed, I hope it shows another way of thinking it.

Comment: What actually is your conjecture? All I see is notion that is poorly defined and no mathematical statement could be called a conjecture.

Comment: ........ So this idea/concept of stating that f(x) = fƧx isn't a conjecture? I guess ideas and concepts stated by an equation is not a conjecture. "Poorly defined"? Thats' awfully biased!

Comment: It is poorly defined though. In another question you yourself said you required a 'formal defintion' of the lambert W function in order to underatand it. I've seen no such defintion for any of the things you wrote down here. What is a 'function modifier', formally speaking?

Comment: "Conjecture: an opinion or conclusion formed on the basis of incomplete information." I think that says it all.

Comment: Also,  'This is not a number or anything like that. It is its own concept, but it can be utilized in an equation.' should say enough. If this is not poorly defined than I don't know what is

Comment: $f(x) = f \ast Ƨx$ isn't a conjecture until you define what $\ast$ and $Ƨx$ are.

Comment: @Sam The informal usage of the word "conjecture" is different than its mathematical usage, much like in science the word "theory" means something very different than in every day speech. If you can give me a definition of $\ast$ and $Ƨx$ as used in $f\ast Ƨx$, and what a function modifier is, maybe we can actually help you. Just so you know, there is no way what you write after can apply to "any functions" as many functions give outputs that have no notion of addition, multiplication or division.

Comment: @James Ok ok ok. Despite all of this, can you just realize it's a concept/idea instead of nitpicking at me for all of "mistakes" in not knowing that a conjecture in casual usage is different in mathematics (which they are pretty similar I think I can get away with using it). Right now you're just criticizing me for my "word choice" instead of trying to use context clues to actual understand the concept. Some people!

Comment: @James "Beforehand, please know that I'm a little bit of an amateur mathemitician" and what part of this do you not understand?

Comment: Discussion of "concept[s]/idea[s]" is not within the scope of this site. Perhaps the part I don't understand is the construct "mathemitician".

Comment: @James $*$ is obviously a multiplication symbol and I defined $Ƨx$ in the post if that made you any happier.

Comment: @James well math is made up only of "concept[s]/idea[s]" so I don'k know how that's possible

Comment: @Sam multiplication is not yet defined for 'function modifiers' and Ƨx, so it's up to you to define what this operator does. Apperently is has as an output a function, but how does it build the function from the function modifier and Ƨx

Comment: You cannot rewrite $$f'(x)= lim(h>0) (f*(Ƨ(x+h)-Ƨ(x)))/h$$ to $$f'(x)*h= lim(h>0) f*(Ƨ(x+h)-Ƨ(x))$$ because $h$ is not defined outside "lim" symbol.

Comment: @sdcvvc Ok. I was unsure about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'solution' is just

$$f(x)\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{f(a+b)}=g(x)$$
So of course plugging in $x=a+b$ yields:
$$f(a+b)\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{f(a+b)}=f(a)+f(b)$$
In the same way as
$$b\frac{a}{b}=a$$

However there is no reason to expect $f(c)+f(d)=g(c+d)$ for any two $c,d$. 
In your own example, set $x=c+d$:
$$\frac{4a(c+d)−2a+4b(c+d)−2b−2(c+d)+2}{2a+2b−1}=g(c+d)$$
And now we see that in this case of course there is no cancellation, and so in general
$$f(c)+f(d)\not=g(c+d)$$
this is only true if $c=a, d=b$, and in that case it's almost a tautology that it's true.

Comment: Well, of course. Still, I proved it using my conjecture. All I wanted to do was defined $g(x)$ with the given equation, and I did that. I even said that you'd be suspicious about this. I'm completely aware of this, though it is still a 'solution' as you so stated.

Comment: Actually, you made an error. There is a cancellation, you just need to factor it out.

Comment: @Sam I don't see it, and I'm pretty sure there is no cancellation. I don't see why $f(c+d)\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{f(a+b)}$ would always cancel and lead to $f(c)+f(d)$

Comment: Wait a seconds... why do we all of a sudden care about $c$ and $d$? This is just in terms of a and b. Maybe I should actually add that to make it known, so my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're trying to do here, however, it doesn't work. From what I understand now, you are 'seperating' the 'input to the function': $Ƨx$, from the 'body of the function': $f$. However this leads to some strange and wrong conclusions, for example:

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{fƧx}{gƧx}=\frac{f}{g}$$
Which is a meaningless result (if I understand your idea correctly), because it's just a 'function modifier' on it's own, without the input. I'm sure there are other more enlighening example of this concept not working out, but right I cannot really think of any of the top of my head.

Ok here is another example:

$$1=\frac{fgƧ^2x}{fgƧ^2x}=\frac{f(g(x))}{g(f(x))}\Leftrightarrow f(g(x))=g(f(x))$$
However this is clearly not true for arbitrary $f,g$.

Comment: I'm not sure how this disproves my conjecture, though I thank you for seeing what I'm going for. That merely says that $$f(x)/g(x)=f/g$$ as a proportion. Now $f/g$ are only function modifiers, so they aren't exact values. Therefore, it would be better to use $f(x)/g(x)$

Comment: We can use this in an example like this: $$Ƨx/Ƨ(x-1)=2$$ for example If we divide a function modifier by the same function modifier $f/f$, we shold get "1". So, we can multiply $f/f$ to that equation so it'll now be $$f*Ƨx/f*Ƨ(x-2)=2$$ and since we're multiplying a function modifier by the $Ƨx$ we get $$f(x)/f(x-1)=2$$. Now we can't just use any old function modifier if there is another function already involved in the equation (an observation after testing) and even if there is one function used, sometimes we don't want that function in our solution so we can't use it